# Failed to merge indices Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing

I have big problem with ES :(
When i insert bulk (size = 20) a lot of document to ES, ES server throw below exception.

I find many topic discuss about this, but nothing. :sosad: , Any help me, what actually happened ??? Thks so much.

Sr for my bad english.

I using ES 2.3 , client Transport 2.2.1.

Server config

```
http.port: 9200
http.max_content_length: 100mb
node.name: "es_test"
nod.master: true
node.data: true
index.store.type: niofs
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 0
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Erros1

```
[2016-03-31 07:45:02,601][ERROR][index.engine             ] [es_test] [my_index][1] failed to merge
java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/1/index/_190.fnm")
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:336)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readByte(BufferedIndexInput.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput.readByte(BufferedChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:101)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:195)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:115)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:99)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4233)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3664)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:588)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:94)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:626)
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum status indeterminate: remaining=0, please run checkindex for more details (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/1/index/_190.fnm")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:371)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:164)
        ... 8 more
[2016-03-31 07:45:02,608][WARN ][index.engine             ] [es_test] [my_index][1] failed engine [already closed by tragic event on the index writer]
java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/1/index/_190.fnm")
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:336)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readByte(BufferedIndexInput.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput.readByte(BufferedChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:101)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:195)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:115)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:99)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4233)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3664)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:588)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:94)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:626)
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum status indeterminate: remaining=0, please run checkindex for more details (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/1/index/_190.fnm")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:371)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:164)
        ... 8 more
[2016-03-31 07:45:02,609][ERROR][index.engine             ] [es_test] [my_index][4] failed to merge
java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/4/index/_190.fdx")
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:336)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readByte(BufferedIndexInput.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput.readByte(BufferedChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:101)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:195)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:133)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:173)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4233)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3664)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:588)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:94)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:626)
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum status indeterminate: remaining=0, please run checkindex for more details (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/es_test/data/es_test/nodes/0/indices/my_index/4/index/_190.fdx")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:371)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:140)
        ... 10 more
```

Erros2

```
[2016-03-31 20:04:07,419][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.node.stats] [es_test] failed to execute on node [mplUA6JET92RPgmNx-DPMA]
RemoteTransportException[[es_test][ip:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]]]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[this IndexReader is closed];
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexReader is closed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.ensureOpen(IndexReader.java:274)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.CompositeReader.getContext(CompositeReader.java:101)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.CompositeReader.getContext(CompositeReader.java:55)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.leaves(IndexReader.java:438)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.Completion090PostingsFormat.completionStats(Completion090PostingsFormat.java:330)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.completionStats(IndexShard.java:765)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.CommonStats.<init>(CommonStats.java:164)
        at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.stats(IndicesService.java:253)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.service.NodeService.stats(NodeService.java:157)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.stats.TransportNodesStatsAction.nodeOperation(TransportNodesStatsAction.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.stats.TransportNodesStatsAction.nodeOperation(TransportNodesStatsAction.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction.nodeOperation(TransportNodesAction.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$NodeTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportNodesAction.java:230)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$NodeTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportNodesAction.java:226)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you receive the error, since upgrading to ES 2.3?

The cause is most likely that your transport client version is older than your clusters version.

When using the transport Client, the versions have to be compatible.

Comment: Before ES 2.3 , I try using ES 2.1 but it same problem, and ES is new deploy :)

Comment: But did you use the same transport client version then ? If the versions don't match, you will have the same problem.

Comment: I think client version have no problem, becasue when I try with ES 2.1, I using same version client , but still erros. :(

Comment: Ok, I see... Did you create the index with Es 1.x, they might not be compatible with ES 2.x.